# How to start an Android application from the command line?

Tags: android, command-line

How to start an Android application from the command line?

There are similar question asked, but I can not find good any answers.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
adb shell
am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Or you can use this directly:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

You can also specify actions to be filter by your intent-filters:

```
am start -a com.example.ACTION_NAME -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Comment: Is activity name compulsory ??

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory.

Comment: Calling the main activity is enough nah ? @Cristian

Comment: If you want to know the activities in an apk, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698814/get-launchable-activity-name-of-package-from-adb

Comment: It's worth mentioning the official docs for the `am start` command: https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#am

Answer (score 31):

You can use:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

This will start the LAUNCHER Activity of the application using monkeyrunner test tool.

Comment: This does not require an activity name like `am`.

Comment: What does an category specify here and how `monkey` helps to identify and start main activitu

Answer (score 13):

Example [here](http://www.android.pk/blog/general/launch-app-through-adb-shell/).

**Pasted below:**

This is about how to launch android application from the adb shell.

Command: `am`

Look for invoking path in AndroidManifest.xml

Browser app::

```
# am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN comp={com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity} }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Settings app::

```
# am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN comp={com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings} }
```

Comment: Is activity name compulsory ??

Comment: Yes, it's irremissible