# Android: merging two diffrent application into one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have source code of two different application.In a separate Project I want to start an application with choice that if a user click option 1 then go to first application and if click on next button then to other application. I made a main page with buttons. Now how do I achieve this task.

Comment: what us the `android-ndk` connection here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to applications that should be started by a third (yours) then make sure those two are installed on your device and start them via `Intent` from your third.

Comment: You could compile those two as library projects and add them to your app.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Look at the `/system/bin/am` command (here: [How to start an Android application from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613889/how-to-start-an-android-application-from-the-command-line)). You can run it from your code with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("PACKAGE NAME OF THE OTHER APPLICATION");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Replace "PACKAGE NAME OF THE OTHER APPLICATION" with the package name of the application that you want to run

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new Activity with 2 buttons and make it MainActvity. From button 1 call MainActivity of the 1st app and from 2nd button call MainActivity of 2nd app using Intent and startActivity().

And make necessary changes in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.