# Android Application combo

Tags: android, android-fragments, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

Can anyone share idea?
We have two applications
ApplicationA
ApplicationB

ApplicationA has menu button to call ApplicationB and before this it checks if application is not installed, it popup msg to install from play but now we want to merge these two projects in one.

We are thinking few possibilities but do not know if technically they are possible

1- Make one installer on google play and when user install ApplicationA, ApplicationB should install automatically but I heard it is not possible.

2- Marge these two projects as one but there are many resource files , language files has same name.

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

If you're just linking to the other Apps you has published, one alternative to consider is [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). This will allow your app to link to other specified applications. If the specified application is not installed, the user is prompted to install it via Google Play.

Another simple method, assuming this is for the applications you has published, would be to link to your [Product List](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html).

Comment: Thanks, we actually do not want to ask users to install another application, we wish when on Google Play press one install button , it should install two applications.
Second option is merging two android project as one (no idea how to merge without errors)

Comment: I don't think it can be apply for button install two application. It against the policy. So second is available, and it needs a little bit efforts. Please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439380/android-merging-two-diffrent-application-into-one) to get some ideas.

Comment: Thanks again, yes we are also thinking on second option.

Comment: We are thinking to merge these two applications (any idea? )

Comment: You can make a new `Activity` with 2 buttons and make it MainActvity. From button 1 call MainActivity of the 1st app and from 2nd button call MainActivity of 2nd app using `Intent` and `startActivity()`.
And make necessary changes in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Does this helped you? If so, please accept. If not please tell me, thanks

Comment: why don't just try copy and combine the file together?