# Launching a shortcut intent from command line terminal with extras?

Tags: android

How can I launch the below intent with extras from the 'am start' command in terminal:

```
Intent;
action=android.intent.action.MAIN;launchFlags=0x14800000;
component=com.google.code.apps2org/com.google.code.appsorganizer.shortcut.LabelShortcut;
l.com.example.android.apis.app.LauncherShortcuts=-2;
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Figured it out...

am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.google.code.apps2org/com.google.code.appsorganizer.shortcut.LabelShortcut --el "com.example.android.apis.app.LauncherShortcuts" "-2" --user 0

Comment: I think this might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613947/1531971